# Is there a tool or a way to open a SWF file to see what's inside?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash, embed

I'm doing some experimenting to try and get the file size smaller and I need to open my swf to make sure some components didn't embed them selfs within the swf. Is there a tool, or a way to open swf to view the contents inside the swf? Such as winrar (which doesn't work) or something of that sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you code using FlashDevelop: http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page, you can just click the plus arrow in the project window:

[image: SWF exploration in FlashDevelop]

FlashDevelop also lets you control the embedding of external SWC easily.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, [swfdump](http://blogs.adobe.com/gosmith/2008/02/disassembling_a_swf_with_swfdu_1.html) I think

Answer (score 0):

A lot of what I do with my OrphanFinder tool can show you what's going on using swfdump.

If you're looking to reduce **PROJECT** size this will be especially helpful.

http://blog.tomschober.com/2011/02/implementing-orphan-finder-for-your-flex-app/
http://blog.tomschober.com/2012/12/flex-orphan-finder-added-to-github/

Answer (score 0):

I had gone through the similar kind of situation.I used 'SWF decompiler'.Its very good but its paid version but trail version willbe also helpful to you.

[SWF decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/)